Can all minimax point of a continuous function on a compact set not being saddle.

Given a continuous function $f:A \subset \mathbb{R}^{2} \to \mathbb{R}$, where we assume $A:=[a_{1},b_{1}] \times [a_{2},b_{2}]$ with $a_{1}<b_{1}$ and $a_{2} < b_{2}$. Suppose $f$ has a infsup point in the interior of $A$, that is there exists point $(x^{*},y^{*}) \subset \operatorname{int}(A)$ such that $f(x^{*}, y^{*})=\inf_{x\in[a_{1}, b_{1}]} \sup_{y \in [a_{2},b_{2}]}$, could it be possible that all infsup point of $f$ are not a saddle points? Where a point $(x^{*},y^{*})$ is said to be a saddle point of $f$ if there exists a neighborhood $\mathcal{N}$ of $(x^{*}, y^{*})$ such that for all $(x,y) \in \mathcal{N}$, $f(x^{*},y)\leq f(x^{*},y^{*})\leq f(x,y^{*})$.

I tried to picture an image in my mind of this happening, though it's possible for me construct functions with at least 1 minimax point that is not a saddle point, I cannot think of example where all minimax points are not saddle.
I was reading about minimax theorems, and I want to get some intuition. I'm think since I have not imposed any convexity condition on $f$ such function should exists. However, I cannot think of concrete examples.
